# Don't need some existed classes in pre-trained models

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Tendorflow object detection.

I know you can train new class with existed pre-trained models in here:

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

But I want to only detect 'person' and 'car',these two classes already existed,futher
training is not neccessary.

However,model such as 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco',It detect 90 classes,and runs too slowly for me.

Is there a way to cut down the classes,so the detection runs faster?

PS:I've filtered COCO dataset to one that only has 'person' and 'car',but following the common steps I googled,I got bad training result.I can only successfully detect 'person'.Wander what's the reason.

Answer (score 1):

Solved myself.If you use 'person' or 'car' in coco,which id is 1 and 3 in pre-trained model,and that cannot be changed.

In .config,set 'num_classes'=3,although your classes num is 2.

The 3 is to fit 'car'-id.

(e.g.If you choose 2 classes,'person'=1,'truck'=8,your 'num_classes' should be 8)

Also,choose your epoch properly,you can see:http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html

Comment: Can you please share more insights on your solution? Did you end up training from scratch? What was your config file? What results did you end up with? I am going through the same dilemma at the moment and would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Changing number of classes, will effect the accuracy (I dont know how much) but it wont change the run-time. running-time is effected by changing number of layers only!

Comment: Nope, changing class nor filter won't improve any performance as the trained Model is already setup to detect all the objects it has been taught to. To fully detect only person and car you would have to train the model to detect only those 2 classes. Even though you won't find a lot performance difference, it depends on the model. The most significant model performance resides on the multiple layers operations for detection. That's why a model like YOLO is faster on low-end devices.